# Django custom connected signal is sent but the method is not ran.. how to fix?

Tags: django, signals

I have a custom connected signal that is not ran:

code in the Contest model in the method add_participant:

```
            # this is called and no error happens
            contest_after_added_participant.send(sender=self, 
                                           participant=participant, 
                                           participation=participation)
```

code in the file that Contest model exists:

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.title += 'sss' # this is never called

contest_after_added_participant = Signal(providing_args=["participant", "participation"])
contest_after_added_participant.connect(my_callback, sender=Contest, dispatch_uid='Contest.001')
```

Answer (score 2):

When sending sender kwarg should be class Contest not instance of Contest. Check:

```
contest_after_added_participant.send(sender=Contest, 
                                 participant=participant, 
                                 participation=participation)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Then I think there is a problem with the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders - "pizza_done.send(sender=self, toppings=toppings, size=size)" ; they are sending an instance.

Comment: You can send signals using instance as sender, but in that case signal should be connected to instance. Yep, your right, they didn't show any full examples of signal usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you call .connect() with a "sender" argument being a Contest **class** and .send() is called, on the other hand, with a Contest **instance**, so they don't match. If you only have one listener for your custom signal and don't need to filter signals sent by specific senders like described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders, then you can just as well remove "sender" argument from your .connect() call:

```
contest_after_added_participant.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid='Contest.001')
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Then I think there is a problem with the documentation: docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/… - "pizza_done.send(sender=self, toppings=toppings, size=size)" ; they are sending an instance.

Comment: No, it is perfectly OK to send an instance in the "sender" argument. And if you wanted to receive your signal for only one particular instance, then you could pass that instance (i.e., an instance with the same primary key) as a "sender" argument to the .connect call.